# MySQL Query in Python

Tags: python, mysql

Following is my code sample.

```
SENTENCE = "Today is a wonderful day."
sent= (word_tokenize(SENTENCE))

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM emotion_state WHERE key_word = %s', (sent))
results = cursor.fetchall()
for i in results:
    print(i)
```

Here I need to check whether the words in "sent" array available in the database or not. If there are some keyword available in the database that is in the "sent" array, I need to fetch all. I'm tried in followed way and it makes the error which is

```
raise errorclass(errorvalue)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during
string formatting
```

How can I do this comparison easily ?

Comment: if `sent` need to be a tuple, you should add a comma inside of it like `(value,)` in case it's a single value.

Comment: @Arount, no, using the `%` operator would make this vulnerable to SQL injection. Letting `execute` do the binding makes it possible to correctly escape the parameters.

Comment: But it makes error

Comment: _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '['It', 'is', 'wonderful', '.']' at line 1")

Comment: @Sjoerd oops, you are right, I deleted this bad advice from the internet :)

Comment: So how can I write the query instead of this way?

Comment: could you print `sent` ? what does `word_tokenize` do/return?

Comment: @ bouletta Yes, I did. it returns ['It', 'is', 'wonderful','day', '.']

Comment: Then using *both* answers provided should solve your problem. replace `=` by `IN` and `(sent)` by `(sent,)`

Comment: @bouletta I did as you said. But it also makes an error

Comment: return "(%s)" % (','.join(escape_sequence(t, d)))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found

Comment: At least you're using placeholders from the get go. See the linked q/a for how to build the placeholders to match the list for IN operator. Or move to Postgresql and let psycopg2 handle lists for you. There's also [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org), which makes life with SQL in Python a lot easier.

Comment: Yeah I got it. If you post this as an answer I can mark it as correct answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably because the last argument in this call is a string, not a tuple:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM emotion_state WHERE key_word = %s', (sent))
```

As you know, a tuple is normally in this form:

```
(a, b, c)
```

However, if it contains only one element you should use an extra comma to indicate that it is a tuple:

```
(a,)
```

Alternatively, you could use a list:

```
[a]
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, the = operator is used to match a single thing. It looks like you want to match a list of things. Try `WHERE key_word IN %s`.

Comment: Yes I want to match a list of thing. could  you please mention the correct statement.

Comment: @Chathurika ...he suggests replacing `=` with `IN`

Comment: @ryugie still the same error